# How to know the compute time needed?

Tags: time

I am working on a project and would like to know if there's a way to roughly estimate the time required for the process to finish. 
My very bad estimate for how many operations would it takes is somewhere between 10^70 and 10^100. I know, huge numbers and I'm almost certain that my computer won't be able to finish in a short time period. (Or ever). How could I get around to knowing how long would it take. (For any project, this is more of an example)

Answer (score 0):

Something with that many operations certainly is looping thru things, possibly in a multi-levelled nested fashion.

If you can find the run time of any of the loops, multiply it by the number of times it loops to get your answer.

Say one loop has 10^10 operations, or 10 billion operations. Say this takes 10 minutes. Well, you can do the math from here.

Comment: I know that much, but I'm looking at where could I find the best estimate for the "10^10 = 10 mimutes"

Comment: Well that's hard to say without actually running it any a given computer as they vary widely in speed and power. My point was to isolate a loop in your program to get a baseline ( something small enough to run within a reasonable amount of time, but large enough to increase the accuracy of your final estimate ).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/) you can find nicely explained material on the topic. This is a short version of the corresponding book chapter ("Algorithms 4th Edition" by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne, chapter "Analysis of Algorithms").

Comment: Posting a link to the reference is nice, but include a relevant blurb so that should the reference ever be dereferenced, those coming in later still have some information to go on.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, modern computers should be able to do 10^8, or 100 000 000 more complex operations in a few seconds.

So if you program competitively, it shouldn't go much over that.

Also, this is just a rule of thumb and slow computers may do significantly worse while there are chips (designed for mining) that can do much much more much faster.
Still a good rule of thumb